# Mapeamento de XML no Excel 2013

Tags: xml, microsoft-excel

Eu tenho uma planilha onde em cada linha eu cadastro um caso de testes e depois o exporto para XML, para então fazer upload deste xml em um outro sistema que utilizamos.

O problema é que consigo fazer apenas de 1 a 1, não consigo preencher várias linhas e depois exportar tudo, quando Eu faço isso o XML exporta apenas a primeira linha e nada mais ou dá um erro que não consigo tratar.

Atualmente exporta desta forma:

```
    <testcases>
<testcase internalid="980" name="Caso de testes Importação">
   <node_order><![CDATA[100]]></node_order>
   <externalid><![CDATA[1]]></externalid>
   <version><![CDATA[1]]></version>
   <summary><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;O caso de teste deve fazer isso   </p>]]></summary>
   <preconditions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;<a id="fck_paste_padding">﻿</a>&nbsp;Pré Condições od caso de testes</p>]]></preconditions>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[1]]></execution_type>
   <importance><![CDATA[2]]></importance>
<steps>
<step>
   <step_number><![CDATA[1]]></step_number>
   <actions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;A1</p>]]></actions>
   <expectedresults><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;EXC1</p>]]></expectedresults>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[1]]></execution_type>
</step>

<step>
   <step_number><![CDATA[2]]></step_number>
   <actions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;A2</p>]]></actions>
   <expectedresults><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;EXC2</p>]]></expectedresults>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[2]]></execution_type>
</step>
</steps>
</testcase>
</testcases>
```

**Mas Eu preciso que exporte desta forma:**

```
<testcases>
   <!-- Aqui começa o caso de teste 1 --> 
<testcase internalid="980" name="Caso de testes Importação">
   <node_order><![CDATA[100]]></node_order>
   <externalid><![CDATA[1]]></externalid>
   <version><![CDATA[1]]></version>
   <summary><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;O caso de teste deve fazer isso   </p>]]></summary>
   <preconditions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;<a id="fck_paste_padding">﻿</a>&nbsp;Pré Condições od caso de testes</p>]]></preconditions>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[1]]></execution_type>
   <importance><![CDATA[2]]></importance>
<steps>
<step>
   <step_number><![CDATA[1]]></step_number>
   <actions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;A1</p>]]></actions>
   <expectedresults><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;EXC1</p>]]></expectedresults>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[1]]></execution_type>
</step>

<step>
   <step_number><![CDATA[2]]></step_number>
   <actions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;A2</p>]]></actions>
   <expectedresults><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;EXC2</p>]]></expectedresults>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[2]]></execution_type>
</step>
</steps>
</testcase>

   <!-- Aqui Termina o caso de teste 1 --> 



      <!-- Aqui começa o caso de teste 2 --> 
<testcase internalid="981" name="Caso de testes Importação">
   <node_order><![CDATA[100]]></node_order>
   <externalid><![CDATA[2]]></externalid>
   <version><![CDATA[1]]></version>
   <summary><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;O caso de teste deve fazer isso   </p>]]></summary>
   <preconditions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;<a id="fck_paste_padding">﻿</a>&nbsp;Pré Condições od caso de testes</p>]]></preconditions>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[1]]></execution_type>
   <importance><![CDATA[2]]></importance>
<steps>
<step>
   <step_number><![CDATA[1]]></step_number>
   <actions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;A1</p>]]></actions>
   <expectedresults><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;EXC1</p>]]></expectedresults>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[1]]></execution_type>
</step>

<step>
   <step_number><![CDATA[2]]></step_number>
   <actions><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;A2</p>]]></actions>
   <expectedresults><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;EXC2</p>]]></expectedresults>
   <execution_type><![CDATA[2]]></execution_type>
</step>
</steps>
</testcase>

   <!-- Aqui Termina o caso de teste 2 --> 

</testcases>
```

[image: erro]

**Estrutura da planilha:**
[image: estrutura]

Comment: tentei escrever aqui no comentário mas não coube tudo que queria colocar, por isso mandei como resposta. ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia!

Até onde sei e trabalhei com XML no Excel, existem dois arquivos um  trabalha com dois arquivos XML, sendo um contendo os dados (.xml) e outro contendo os esquemas (.xsd).

Não sei como está seu mapa XML no Excel que pode ser visualizado via aba *Desenvolvedor* > *Código Fonte (XML)*, contudo, alguns parâmetros que o Excel entendo como dados repetidos são `<xsd:sequence>` (tudo junto).

Segue abaixo um exemplo de esquema funcionado para exportação de múltiplos dados:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Cadastro">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Pessoa">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
              <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Nome" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Nascimento" type="xsd:date"/>
              <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Telefone" />
              <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Calc" />
              <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Test" type="xsd:integer"/>
            </xsd:all>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>        
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Para testar, segue um passo a passo:

1. Salve esse código acima num documento com extensão *.xsd* (ex. *mapa_cadastro.xsd*)
2. Abra o Excel, na guia desenvolvedor clique em Código-fonte, na opção XML, clique em *Mapas XML* e adicione o mapa XML salvo (*mapa_cadastro.xsd*), conforme abaixo:

[image: Imagem de como importar o mapa xml]

3. Após visualizar o mapa, selecione todos os itens e cole na planilha, conforme figura abaixo:

[image: Selecionar mapas para a planilha]

4. Insira alguns dados e faça a exportação em XML via aba *Desenvolvedor* > *Exportar (XML)*

Todos os dados, incluindo todas as linhas preenchidas, estarão no seu XML.

Espero ter ajudado.

[EDIÇÃO 1]

Se tiver o seu XML pronto, um exemplo do que precisa, com múltiplas linhas, pode tentar importar o arquivo (.xml) para o Excel, que vai gerar o mapa automaticamente para você.

Tente depois disso alterar os dados, inserir novas linhas e exportar, isso também deve funcionar, porém não terá o mapa (.xsd) desenhado para editar alguma informação (cabeçalho) ou tipo de dado que precisa ser exportado no XML.